# Host ASP.NET Core 3.1 Angular Template in IIS The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core-3.1

We are trying to put the default ASP.NET Core 3.1 template with Angular into IIS as a test and we are getting the following errors:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
>   main-es2015.7a946a5153b4f357caaf.js:1
>
> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
>   polyfills-es2015.27661dfa98f6332c27dc.js:1
>
> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

We have published the application to the folder structure with a release build.  The program and startup are as the default template creates.  We have installed the dotnet-hosting package as well.

Are there additional configuration steps required in IIS to host this as the documentation doesn't allude to anything else that is required.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you installed static content content feature for your IIS server? It sounds like your server can't handle the type correct because mime type are not configured correct.

Comment: Were you able to make any progress with this?  I ran into the same issue with creating a brand new project and debugging in IISExpress